# Does Caffe contain a static initialization fiasco?

Tags: c++, caffe

When I run Caffe.exe, it does this:

```
cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, 0);
Caffe::SetDevice(0);
Caffe::set_mode(Caffe::GPU);
Net<float> caffe_net(modelFile, caffe::TEST);
caffe_net.CopyTrainedLayersFrom(weightsFile);
```

and all the Layers are statically added to the LayerRegistry and everything runs as expected.

But if I make Net a pointer member of an enclosing class and put the initialization within the constructor, then the Layers are *not* statically added to the LayerRegistry:

```
class Foo
{
   Foo();
   std::unique_ptr< Net<float> > net;
}

Foo::Foo()
{
   cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
   cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, 0);
   Caffe::SetDevice(0);
   Caffe::set_mode(Caffe::GPU);
   Net<float> caffe_net(modelFileName, caffe::TEST);
   net.reset(new Net<float>(modelFileName, caffe::TEST));
   net->CopyTrainedLayersFrom(weightsFileName);
}
```

In layer_factory.* I see that layers have the macro REGISTER_LAYER_CREATOR where the macro is defined as:

```
#define REGISTER_LAYER_CREATOR(type, creator)                                  \
  static LayerRegisterer<float> g_creator_f_##type(#type, creator<float>);     \
  static LayerRegisterer<double> g_creator_d_##type(#type, creator<double>)    \
```

Does Caffe contain a [static initialization fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order)?

Comment: I don't know `Caffe` at all so take this with a grain of salt. What's the relationship between the code in `Foo::Foo()` and `REGISTER_LAYER_CREATOR`?

Comment: @RSahu Net contains a statically initialized Layer registry which statically initializes based on the macros.  Caffe is...complicated so someone with knowledge of it will probably need to answer.

Comment: Have you tried compiling with `-Wl,--no-as-needed` (or whatever the MSVC equivalent of that is)?

Comment: @TravisGockel which compiler's switches are you talking about?

Comment: In GCC/LLVM land, `-Wl,...` is an argument to pass along to the linker. The reason I say this is that as long as whatever you're doing is happening after `main` is entered, it is unlikely to be a static-initialization issue. What I'm totally guessing here is something strange with underlinking (where the final binary drops translations not used directly). Since the resulting `g_creator_f_thing` symbol isn't used from your `main` TU, the linker might be dropping it and, hence, the action associated with the symbol. Have you tried moving the class definition to `main.cpp` (or where `main` is)?

Comment: Thanks, @TravisGockel!  Your comments sent me on the path to the answer.

Comment: Good deal...glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "No."

The problem, as @TravisGockel notes in the comments above is that the LayerRegisterer constructors need to be forced to link with the DLL or executable when they are in a static library.

For Visual Studio C++, as noted in [Forcing Construction of Global Objects in Static Libraries](https://ofekshilon.com/2013/04/06/forcing-construction-of-global-objects-in-static-libraries/), the solution is to force the linking of these constructors by setting `Project|Properties|References|libcaffe|Project Reference Properties|Use Library Dependency Inputs` to `true`.